# Changing random_state in sklearn methods (after tuning of hyperparams) provide different accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-seed

I'm taking a course in stat learning / ML, currently doing a project including a classification task, and I have some newbie questions regarding the random_state parameter. The accuracy of my model is heavily changing depending on the random_state. I'm currently working with logistic regression (from sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()). I try to tune the hyperparameter by using the GridSearchCV method.

The problem:
I get different prediction accuracy, depending on which random_state I'm using.

What I have tried:
I have tried to set the random_state parameter as a global state (using np.random.seed(randomState) and setting randomState as an integer in the top of the script). Further, I split the data using the

```
train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=randomState)
```

with the same (global) integer randomState. Further, I want to preform GridSearchCV to tune the hyperparameters. Thus, I specify a param_grid and preform a GridSearchCV on this. From this, I find the best estimator and choose this as my model. Then, I use my model for prediction and print a classification report of the results. I take the average out of 10 runs by changing the randomState.

Example: I do this procedure with randomState=1 and find the best model from GridSearchCV: model_1. I get the accuracy 84%. If Im changing to randomState = 2,...,10 and still use model_1, the average accuracy becomes 80.5%.
I do this procedure with randomState=42 and find the best model from GridSearchCV: model_42. I get the accuracy 77%. If Im changing to randomState = 41, 40, 39,..,32 and still use model_42, the average accuracy becomes 78.7%.

I'm very confused why the accuracy varies so much depending on random_state.

Answer (score 0):

Tuning random_state gives you different accuracies. Random state is like randomly splitting the dataset into train and test rather than splitting the dataset according to ascending values of index. This results in splitting of data-points into train and test and if there is any point in test data which is not there in train data, then this may lead to poor accuracies. The best way to deal this problem is by using Cross-validation Split. In this approach which randomly split the data into train and test then perform machine learning modelling, and this step is repeated for n times where n is number of splits (mostly n = 5). Then we take the mean of all accuracies and will consider this accuracy to be the final result. Instead of changing the value random_state every-time you can perform Cross-validation Split

You can find references to this in the below link:

[https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/#:~:text=Cross%2Dvalidation%20is%20a%20resampling,k%2Dfold%20cross%2Dvalidation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/#:%7E:text=Cross%2Dvalidation%20is%20a%20resampling,k%2Dfold%20cross%2Dvalidation)